# Genitive plural opinions! Which is correct: Tomorrow the sister of a university friend of Clare and John is getting married. Or of Clare's and John's?

Tags: possessives, plural-forms, apostrophe, names

Native speaker here confused about genitive case.

Genitive plural opinions! Which is correct:

- Tomorrow the sister of a university friend of Clare and John is getting married
- Tomorrow the sister of a university friend of Clare's and John's is getting married

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "Friend of P" and "Friend of P's" mean the inverse of each other?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48328/how-do-friend-of-p-and-friend-of-ps-mean-the-inverse-of-each-other) Also [Double Possessive - two friends of hers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212425/double-possessive-two-friends-of-hers)

Comment: ...there's also my own question about this, as asked on ELU some years ago: [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/)

Comment: ...you missed out the possibility of ***friend of Clare and John's***, as might be used by a speaker who thinks that because "Clare and John" are [***an item***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-an-item), they can share one possessive apostrophe between the two of them.